# ssh Permission denied (publickey) Bind to port 22 on 0.0.0.0 failed: Address already in use

Tags: ssh, vmware, public-key, ubuntu-11.04

I'm trying to add a key public key for my dev box which is a vm running ubuntu natty, and I am unable to connect via ssh. I've tried rsa and dsa, as well as these commands:

```
exec ssh-agent bash
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_dsa
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=0
```

I also edited my sshd_config file as follows:

```
ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

I've tried restarting sshd as well as the system, too.

I think I've found the error by running sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -Dd, but I'm not sure how to fix it:

```
ebug1: sshd version OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-1ubuntu3
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: private host key: #0 type 1 RSA
debug1: read PEM private key done: type DSA
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.DSA-1024
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.DSA-1024
debug1: private host key: #1 type 2 DSA
debug1: rexec_argv[0]='/usr/sbin/sshd'
debug1: rexec_argv[1]='-Dd'
Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj from 0 to -1000
debug1: Bind to port 22 on 0.0.0.0.
Bind to port 22 on 0.0.0.0 failed: Address already in use.
Cannot bind any address.
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Belongs to http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 2):

It looks like another process is already running that's bound to port 22. Find out which:

```
sudo netstat -lnp --inet
```

Then kill it and try again.

Comment: tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      657/nginx       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      656/sshd        
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           642/dhclient3

Comment: Well, plainly `sshd` is already running. Stop it before you try to start it again.